# play videos from my youtube channel in android

Tags: android, youtube

I am making an application where I need to list the playlists of a corresponding YouTube channel. I have a working YouTube player. Now what I need is to get the list of playlists of the channel with its video thumbnail and also all the video IDs. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [you tube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_audience) for example to get a playlist

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLAYLIST_ID
```

Comment: thank you for reply. I want to play videos from my youtube channel. for example my youtube channel is [link] http://www.youtube.com/mrEncros/

Comment: To get a users playlist use `https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/userId/playlists?v=2` replacing the userId `https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/mrencros/playlists?v=2`

Comment: i want to get list of all videos from my youtube channel and display in listview and then play specific on user's choice. can you please explain in deep?

Comment: See this [page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_playlists#Retrieving_playlists) for explanation

Comment: you can use the HttpClient class to get the data from the API, then you will need to parse it into a list of objects that you can bind to your list.Look at subclassing the ArrayAdapter

Comment: Look at the API Demos that come with Android there is lots of examples in there of binding to a list.

Comment: i don't find the demo for this same from API Demos that come with Android. Can you give the URL from which i get the demos. Thank you so so so much.

Comment: Look at the [list examples](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/index.html) list1.java , list2.java etc

Comment: Thank you for all. I got Demo from http://blog.blundell-apps.com/click-item-in-a-listview-to-show-youtube-video/#comment-467

Answer (score 3):

This question is very old, however it will helpful for those developers who is looking for youtube channel integration in Android App. I am presenting a rough idea. You can follow this tutorial [Youtube channel integration in Android](http://www.techiesatish.com/youtube-channel-integration-android-using-youtubeplayerview/) Follow these steps:-

1. Find youtube channel id.
2. Genrete SHA1 key
3. Get API Key for Youtube Data API v3 and paste SHA1 key in restriction of use
4. Get Channel video list and description with thumbnail image in JSON format from this [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) by clicking on **Load in APIs Explorer**. Put your channel id in **ChannelId** textfield you will get JSON format data of videos.
5. Add internet permission in AndroidManifest file.
6. [Download](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/) the YoutubePlayerApi.jar file in your library of Android projects and volley library in build.gradle file.
7. Create a Channel Activity and use JSON parsing to parse the Video list.
8. Pass the videoId from yourAdapter to another Activity by intent.putExtra().
9. Get the videoId in another Activity by getExtra().
10. show video by using cueVideo().